# How can I make registered extensions for `binfmt_misc` persist across reboots?

Tags: linux, bash, debian, kernel, binfmt

How can I make registered extensions for `binfmt_misc` persist across reboots?

Consider the following command, which performs a `binfmt_misc` registration:

```
echo ':golang:E::go::/tmp/test:OC' | sudo tee /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register
```

It needs to be executed as `root`, since only `root` is allowed to write to `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register`. Thus, I cannot put such registrations into e.g. `~/.bashrc` as an unprivileged user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you’re using Debian, you could install [`binfmt-support`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/binfmt-support) and register your extension using [`update-binfmts`](https://manpages.debian.org/binfmt-support/update-binfmts.8):

```
sudo update-binfmts --install golang /tmp/test --extension go --credentials yes
```

If that works, you can store the `binfmt_misc` specification in a file under `/usr/share/binfmts`, which will ensure it’s loaded every time the system boots:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /usr/share/binfmts/golang
package <local>
interpreter /tmp/test
extension go
credentials yes
EOF
```

To check the above works, run

```
sudo update-binfmts --import golang
```

Alternatively, you can use [systemd’s support for `binfmt_misc`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/binfmt.d.html):

```
echo ':golang:E::go::/tmp/test:OC' | sudo tee /etc/binfmt.d/golang.conf
```

This will be loaded at boot by [`systemd-binfmt.service`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-binfmt.service.html#) .

Comment: Weird, `/usr/share/binfmts` already exists (and contains `python3` support), but `binfmt-support` is not installed? Does `binfmt-support` install a `systemd` service, or how are the  specifications loaded on boot? Finally, do you know if `systemd` provides support for `binfmt_misc`? I read some comments that it might do.

Comment: Packages install `binfmt-support` files so that, if `binfmt-support` is installed, their entries are automatically registered (in the same way as `logrotate` configuration files etc.). `binfmt-support` installs an init script and a systemd service. See the forthcoming update re systemd support.

Comment: Thanks :) - Since `systemd` now provides `binfmt_misc` support doesn't that makes `binfmt-support` obsolete?

Comment: For systems using systemd, yes, but Debian doesn’t mandate systemd.

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get install binfmt-support

#Python3 on Raspberry Pi OS (11)

sudo update-binfmts --install python3 /usr/bin/python3 --credentials yes --magic 610d0d0a

Installing the app and issuing the above command will execute my compiled python3 files. For example I have a pyc file I simply named calc. It fires if I just type the name. Thanks for the great information.